# get() returned more than one Sub_Topic -- it returned 3

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have started a project using Django. Where I used add multiple sub-topics under one main topic by taking `staticid`. When I am giving same `staticid` to multiple sub-topics, I am getting the error below (`get() returned more than one Sub_Topic -- it returned 3!`).

Model:

```
class Sub_Topic(models.Model):
    IMPORTANCE_SCORE = (
        ('LOW','Low'),
        ('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
        ('HIGH','High'),
    )
    staticid = models.ForeignKey(SID,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    sub_topic = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Num_Of_Sub_subTopics =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    Num_Of_Questions = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices= IMPORTANCE_SCORE, default='LOW')
    complexity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    prerequisite = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_topic
```

View:

```
class Sub_TopicDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    GET sub_topic/:id/
    PUT sub_topic/:id/
    DELETE sub_topic/:id/
    """
    queryset = Sub_Topic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Sub_TopicSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(staticid=kwargs["staticid"])
            return Response(Sub_TopicSerializer(a_sub_topic).data)
        except Sub_Topic.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Sub_Topic with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["staticid"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )

    @validate_request_data
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(staticid=kwargs["staticid"])
            serializer = Sub_TopicSerializer()
            updated_sub_topic = serializer.update(a_sub_topic, request.data)
            return Response(Sub_TopicSerializer(updated_sub_topic).data)
        except Sub_Topic.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Sub_Topic with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["staticid"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
```

Error:

```
get() returned more than one Sub_Topic -- it returned 3!
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: This is expected, `staticid` is not a unique field of `Sub_Topic`. `get()` returns the object matching the given lookup parameters and raises ` MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one object was found. 
You should lookup for a subtopic by your id or another unique lookup

Comment: a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(id=kwargs["id"]) KeyError: 'id' [28/Jan/2019 09:59:35] "GET /quiz/subtopics/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18980 Iam getting this error can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a main topic (say, "donuts"), and many subtopics within that ("plain donuts", "chocolate donuts", "vanilla donuts", ...), you cannot reference a subtopic by just saying "donuts", you have to be more specific.

Your sub-topic views should accept a sub-topic ID, not the main topic ID. Try changing this:

```
a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(staticid=kwargs["staticid"])
# 'staticid' is the foreign key of the main topic: it is
# the same for many sub-topics!
```

to this:

```
a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(id=kwargs["id"])
# 'id' is the primary key field generated automatically by Django:
# it's unique for every sub-topic
```

If instead you want to display all sub-topics for a given topic, then you should use `filter()` instead of `get()`:

```
sub_topics = self.queryset.filter(staticid=kwargs["staticid"])
```

Comment: a_sub_topic = self.queryset.get(id=kwargs["id"])
KeyError: 'id'
[28/Jan/2019 09:59:35] "GET /quiz/subtopics/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18980
Iam getting this error can you explain me why?

Comment: but its just returning only one subtopic per id, but i want to display all the subtopics under maintopic

Comment: If that's the case, you have to use filter(), which will return multiple objects (updated answer). Note though that, depending on how the rest of the code behaves, you _might_ have to adjust your serializers

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `sub_topic` on serializer `Sub_TopicSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sub_topic'.

Please help me how do i overcome on this?

Comment: class Sub_TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sub_Topic
        fields = ('staticid','sub_topic','Num_Of_Sub_subTopics','Num_Of_Questions',
        'importance','complexity','prerequisite')
This is my serializer....